# Does __ne__ use an overridden __eq__?

Tags: python, comparison, equality

Suppose I have the following program:

```
class A(object):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

a0 = A() 
a1 = A() 
print a0 != a1
```

If you run it with Python the output is `True`. My question is

1. the `__ne__` method is not implemented, does Python fall on a default one?
2. if Python fall on a default method to determine whether two objects are equal or not, shouldn't it call `__eq__` and then negate the result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__):

> There are no implied relationships among the comparison operators. The truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false. Accordingly, when defining  `__eq__()`, one should also define `__ne__()` so that the operators will behave as expected.

Comment: So if ``__ne__`` is not implemented, shouldn't Python throw a exception if I use ``!=`` to compare two objects?

Comment: @dorafmon: no, because the default implementation doesn't consult `__eq__`, it simply returns `self is not other`.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick answer

> *[if]* the `__ne__` method is not implemented, does Python fall on a default one?

Generally speaking, yes, it does - but the point is: *what the behavior of the default `__ne__` is*. And that depends on the version of Python (please read on).

> if Python fall on a default method to determine whether two objects are equal or not, shouldn't it call `__eq__` and then negate the result?

- Python 2.x: it does not. On `self != other`, if no custom `__ne__` is provided by `self` or `other` then only object identities are checked (so the effective behavior is equivalent to `self is not other`).
- Python 3.x: indeed, the default implementation of `__ne__` calls `__eq__` and negates the result (but on the technical level there are some subtleties, please read on).

### Interlude: what happens when `__ne__` returns `NotImplemented`

Each of the Python's “rich comparison” methods, including `__ne__`, can **either** give a resolute answer (typically: `True` or `False`) **or** say *I don't know!* by returning a special singleton object, [`NotImplemented`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy) (warning: *not* to be confused with [`NotImplementedError`!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError)).

On `self != other`, first `self.__ne__(other)` is called, and if it returns `NotImplemented` then Python tries `other.__ne__(self)` (however, if the type of `other` is a subclass of the type of `self` but not the same type then the order is reverse: `other.__ne__(self)` is called first, and only if it returns `NotImplemented` the `self.__ne__(other)` call is tried). If both calls returned `NotImplemented` then Python falls back to an object-identity-based check (`self is not other`).

The behavior related to `==` and `__eq__` is analogous.

That's what is referred to by the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__) in the fragment:

> `__eq__()` and `__ne__()` are their own reflection

*Note*: this fragment should be understood as: *`__eq__()` is its own reflection* and *`__ne__()` is its own reflection* (each on its own, separately).

### Python 2.x behavior

As Ami Tavory wrote, when it comes to the standard behavior and default implementations, *there are no implied relationships between `__ne__` and `__eq__`.*

### Python 3.x behavior

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__):

> For `__ne__()`, by default it delegates to `__eq__()` and inverts the result unless it is `NotImplemented`.

In other words, the behavior of `object.__ne__` is (roughly) equivalent to:

```
def __ne__(self, other):
    res = self.__eq__(other)
    if res is NotImplemented:
        return NotImplemented
    return not res
```

Of course, `object.__ne__` can be shadowed by another implementation provided by a subclass. That's why, when you implement a subclass of, for example, `dict`, if you want to provide your customized `__eq__` you also need to provide `__ne__` (whose implementation can be just as in the above code snippet, or even shorter: `return object.__ne__(self, other)`).